# http status code 200

Tags: php, http

Can any one please let me know the exact meaning of `http status code 200`.

Because, i have uploaded the file to a particular folder `(NewsToday)` having protocol `HTTPS`, but it does not post that file into that folder, instead shows an `error status code 200`. Why? What i did the mistake i did?

Answer (score 4, accepted):

It means:

> The request sent by the client was
>   successful.

More Info:

http://www.w3.org/Protocols/rfc2616/rfc2616-sec10.html

Also post your code for us to see how you are doing it. Also, since you are doing it on secure protocol, make sure that you have **openssl** extension turned on.

Comment: Hello...where do i check this openssl extension

Comment: @PHP-Prabhu: It should be in php.ini file. Search for the term **openssl** and remove comment `;` symbol in front of that.

Comment: 200 means a bit more than "the request sent by the client was successful", all the 2xx status codes do.

Answer (score 2):

The HTTP status code 200 means OK. It's not supposed to be an error. If you're interested, you can see a bunch of other HTTP status codes [here](http://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/List_of_HTTP_status_codes).